# Python datetime format mask

Tags: python

I have the following datetime format to parse into datetime object in python:

```
Wed, 13 Jul 2011 09:11:14 +0200
```

What format mask should I use for `+0200` part? It means +2 hours.

The thing is that I can't even find any man page on the Internet about datetime format masks.

Comment: Have you solved? If you did, and any of these answers contained the solution, you should mark it as accepted (should you have 15+ points of reputation by when you read this, you should also consider upvoting answers that were somehow useful for you. [Sorry if you already knew this, but you being new to the site, I thought you might have not known yet]

Answer (score 1):

like this?

```
In [10]: now = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime("Wed, 13 Jul 2011 09:11:14 +0200", "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0200")[0:5])

In [11]: now
Out[11]: datetime.datetime(2011, 7, 13, 9, 11)
```

See [doc.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime)

For everything related to time and dates, I turn to [pleac](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html)

Answer (score 1):

It really depends fro what you mean by "parsing". What should happen to the timezone information?

If you intend to purely discard it, you can then instantiate a **naïve datetime object** as suggested by Fredrik in his answer.

If you intend to retain that information you must create an **aware datetime object** by setting the `tzinfo` attribute of your `datetime` instance. [This](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html?highlight=tzinfo#datetime.datetime.tzinfo) is the relevant documentation.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) you could use `%z`, but it [turns out](http://bugs.python.org/issue6641) it's platform dependent and is not working on my machine. Check it out.